# How to access Page.Header.Controls in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to access Page.Header.Controls in ASP.NET MVC 2?

## Edit

I want to create a helper which can manage scripts.

Yesterday, after I asked this question I discovered, that ViewPage and ViewUserControl has Page property.

I think this allows us to access Page.Header.Controls.

Comment: more info please.. if you want your question to be answered, please provide more info..

Answer (score 4):

**No**, `Page.Header` doesn't exist in ASP.NET MVC. `Header` is the `<head runat="server>` control in ASP.NET Web Forms. ASP.NET MVC doesn't use controls like that.

If you want logic in the `<head>` of your HTML, you have to go about it the ASP.NET MVC way, by using code in your view or your master page.

The `Page` property of a `ViewPage` comes from the fact that Web Form Views are bastard Web Forms. ASP.NET MVC normally doesn't use any bits of the Web Forms beside the code-in-front and the markup, but via various unsupported haacks you can abuse it into letting you use other Web Forms stuff. Don't do it.